# Netbeans and Codename One

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

I have installed the Netbeans Codename One plugin.

I then go to File->New Project->Codename One->Codename One Project

I work my way through the wizard entering the project details as I go.
Eventually I click 'Finish' ... but the project does not show up in the Project explorer.

So I thought I would try and manually open the new project, but when I select the project I get this error ...

" unrecognized project; missing plug-in? "

But I have installed the plugin.

I have had a look at the TYPE value in project.xml and is says

" org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject "

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What JDK are you running NetBeans on? Which version of NetBeans? We introduced support for newer JDK's but that's still in beta. Can you check the netbeans log to see if something is logged there? Does the `.codenameone` directory in your home directory exist? What does it contain? Can you run the designer jar from there if it's there?

Comment: [1] Go to **Tools > Plugins >** Select the **Installed** tab > Select the **User Installed Plugins** entry > In the right panel titled _User Installed Plugins_ scroll down and verify that there is an entry named **CodenameOnePlugin**. If there is not then the plugin was not installed successfully, so check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) for any relevant errors. Update your post accordingly. [2] Per Shai's comment, update your post with the versions of NetBeans and JDK being used.